# Can I tell PL/SQL collection with deleted last element from trimmed PL/SQL collection?

Tags: oracle, collections, plsql

Just theoretical question:

Nested tables can become sparse due to deletions, which can be proven by founding holes in sequence of indexes from `first` across `next`s until `last`.
However, if `last` index is deleted, the collection bounds are exactly same as if `last` index were trimmed (or as if collection was never extended to that index).
Is there any way to distinguish this difference?

```
declare
  type ct is table of varchar2(200);
  a ct := ct('x','y','z');
  b ct := ct('x','y','z');
begin
  a.delete(3);
  b.trim();
  -- first=1, last=2, count=2 here for both a and b
  a(3) := 'l'; -- legal since delete keeps room for 3rd element extended
  --b(3) := 'l'; -- illegal since trim is inversion of extend
end;
```

In other words, if Alice deletes and Bob trims, can I tell who made which collection (except making attempt to insert at index `last+1` and catch potential ORA-06533 `Subscript beyond count` error)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference here is that after `delete` the nested table becomes *sparse* but after `trim` it remains *dense*. PL/SQL provides no (easy) tools to check if a nested table is sparse or dense - it is a programmer responsibility to know all the time if he's working with a sparse or dense nested table.

In your particular example after `a.delete(3)` or `b.trim` PL/SQL provides you no tool to programmatically check if `a(3) := 'x'` or `b(3) := 'x'` is valid or not. Except, as you pointed, try it and catch the potential exception. In general you have to keep track of the nested table size.

My rule-of-thumb is that one always keeps his nested tables dense and uses *associative array* for sparse collections. If you need only a subset of nested table elements create a new dense nested table for the subset.

**Example**

```
declare
  type str_list_t is table of varchar2(1);

  a str_list_t := str_list_t('a', 'b', 'c'); -- dense
  b str_list_t := str_list_t('a', 'b', 'c'); -- dense

  procedure d(p_strs in str_list_t) is
    s varchar2(32767);
  begin
    s := '(count ' || p_strs.count || ')';
    s := s || '(first ' || p_strs.first || ')';
    s := s || '(last ' || p_strs.last || ')';

    s := s || '(';
    for i in p_strs.first .. p_strs.last
    loop
      s := s || '(' || i || ' ' || p_strs(i) || ')';
    end loop;
    s := s || ')';

    dbms_output.put_line(s);
  end;
begin
  a.delete(3); d(a); -- collection becomes sparse
  b.trim;      d(b); -- remains dense

  -- exists won't help you as a(3) doesn't exists and exists returns false
  if a.exists(3) then a(3) := 'C'; end if;
  if b.exists(3) then b(3) := 'C'; end if;

  d(a);
  d(b);

  a(3) := 'D'; d(a); -- ok
  b(3) := 'D'; d(b); -- ORA-06533: Subscript beyond count
end;
/
```

**Results**

```
(count 2)(first 1)(last 2)((1 a)(2 b))
(count 2)(first 1)(last 2)((1 a)(2 b))
(count 2)(first 1)(last 2)((1 a)(2 b))
(count 2)(first 1)(last 2)((1 a)(2 b))
(count 3)(first 1)(last 3)((1 a)(2 b)(3 D))
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06533: Subscript beyond count
ORA-06512: at line 35
```

Comment: Thanks for thorough answer. I kind of expected it. It's pity such information is not easily available (for example `limit` is not utilized for nested tables, it could return internal capacity).